# Is there an Umbraco plugin to give CRM-type capabilities?

Tags: umbraco, contacts

In looking at the [Kentico documentation for account and contact management](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Organizing+contacts+into+accounts), it seems to give us the ability to create a hierarchy for accounts, such as Account (Client) / Organizational Unit (store locations) / Contact (person at location).

I am looking for a way to accomplish this in Umbraco.  We would also want to add multiple fields to the Contact, as they may exist in multiple organizational units.

Is it possible to accomplish this with Umbraco, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free and open-source (according to the latest update from the creator: https://twitter.com/theotron/status/784372313773006849) plugin called **Pipeline CRM**: https://www.pipelinecrm.co.uk. Source code and installation details are also available on Github: https://github.com/theotron/PipelineCRM.

There's also **uSightly**, which integrates with Insightly:
https://our.umbraco.org/projects/collaboration/usightly/

I've not used either personally, so I don't know if they would meet your requirements. You can also integrate with other CRM systems yourself if you wish, I know of developers who've integrated with CRMs like Salesforce and Dynamics from Umbraco.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just to add something to this post - Pipeline CRM is now free and open source: https://twitter.com/theotron/status/784372313773006849

Comment: Awesome, didn't realise it was free now!